# Web Service Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, xml-serialization, web

I'd like to create a class A_bis witch inherits from class  A
Some fields of class A are nullable (  `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]`) . Others not ...
I'm interested in the others to become nullable in the class A_bis.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this by inheritance. You will have to modify the base class.